# Body parser's req.body keeps returning undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

The `Content-Type` of the header is set to `application/JSON` this way, I believe. My input fields are enveloped in a `<form method="POST">` with a `type="submit"` input field inside. Why do I get `undefined` for the body then? What's an alternative module to the body parser?

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = require('express')(),
    cookieSession = require('cookie-session'),
    ejs = require('ejs'),
    path = require('path'),
    cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    auth = require('./middleware/auth.js'),
    user = require('./models/user.js'),
    router = express.Router();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    //returns undefined
    console.log(req.body);
    user.create(req.session.username, req.session.email, req.session.password);
    res.render('./game/game.html', {});
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('./index.html', {});
});

app.get('/game', function (req, res) {
   res.render('/views/index.html');
});

//expose router constructor
module.exports = router;

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: You are submitting a request with content-type JSON, but the form data won't be in JSON format will it? I think you need to change the content to type to correspond to form data instead.

Comment: What you're experiencing most likely means that the data you're passing through to your express app is not valid JSON. `body-parser` doesn't throw an error when you don't receive valid JSON, instead you'll just have no body, which is what you have here. If you open up a `REPL` session and try  `JSON.parse()` on the body in question do you receive an error?

Comment: Try to give body parser in on before template engine .It was worked in my case